# Polynomial transform of a Gaussian Random Variable

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, polynomial

I have been trying to find how the PDF of a polynomial transform of a Gaussian Random Variable could be found. Eg:
If
\begin{equation}
\ X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
Then what would be the  distribution of $Y$
\begin{equation}
\ Y = aX^3 + bX^2 +cX +d
\end{equation}
Is there any method, analytically, or numerically to find it?

Comment: Since $X=\mu+\sigma Z$, with $Z\sim \text{N}(0,1)$, you can simplify the problem into $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1$. From there, you should first consider solving $Y\le y$ in terms of constraints on $X$ towards deriving the pdf of $Y$, but I am unsure there exists an analytical solution. Maybe start with a second degree polynomial?

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for your reply. I do not quite follow what you mean by your second sentence. Even if X is replaced with Z we still encounter a polynomial function. Does it mean the terms can be evaluated individually and summed?

Comment: Consider solving $aX^3+bX^2+X\le y$ as imposing a condition on $X\sim\text{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Xi'an. Let me ask you one more question. Is it possible to solve it by taking the first 4 moments of $Y$. Then using the skew and kurtosis to build a skew normal /non-normal distribution based on $X$?

Comment: Polynomials are pretty nasty: they tend to be many-to-one transformations and in general you can only obtain approximate or numerical solutions. Do you have specific values of the coefficients in mind?

Comment: I was suggesting the inequality above so that you could solve a 3rd degree equation. Using moments does not give you a distribution.

Comment: @whuber there are specific values for the coefficients. Which are actually polynomials out of a 3rd degree curve fitting of a transfer characteristic, which we apply to a gaussian RV input. Solving such a curve fitting approximation may be difficult for real values. Is it possible that a second order polynomial ($a=0$) could potentially be converted to chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom $Y = b(X+\frac{c}{2b})^2 + (d-\frac{c^2}{4b})$

Comment: The second order situation yields, in general, a [non-central $\chi^2$ variate.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution#Background) The big distinction, in general, is whether the derivative of your polynomial has less than two real roots (in which case the polynomial gives a monotonic transformation and numerical methods are fairly easy to apply) or has two real roots and at least one lies within the interval $[\mu-6\sigma,\mu+6\sigma]$ or thereabouts (requiring a fussier implementation of numerical methods).

Comment: Why don't you simulate and use the empirical distribution as an approximation? This should be easy.